# Eclipse content assist for Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, gradle, aether

I'm using the Grails Tool Suite (Eclipse) and for a Grails project I cannot figure out a good way to get Eclipse content assist working for a library (Google Guava) that is a dependency via Gradle. I can add the libraries to the build path after they've been downloaded, but I hope there is something better so that I don't have to start managing jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made a mistake. I'm not using Gradle I'm using the default engine Aether. And I believe I found the fix, Right Click -> Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Have You tried using the [Eclipse plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) to generate correct classpath entries?

Add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to Your build file, run `gradle eclipse` and refresh the project

Comment: This will be other (older) way to manage dependencies. Both way do not have something to do with content assist.